# Can a continuous preference be represented by a discountinuous function?

Tags: utility, preferences

I can think of some examples, but what can be an outline of the proof?

Comment: A continuous preference relation can always be represented by a continuous function. However,  It can also be represented bu other (nom-continuous) functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed you are correct that a continuous utility function can be represented by a discontinuous function. However, I am not sure what you mean by proof beyond an example; an example **is** a proof of this fact.

For completeness, here is an example we can take $\succeq\,\subset \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ to reflect the usual ordering (i.e., $x \succeq y$ iff $x \geq y$). Clearly this is a continuous ordering as its contour sets are intervals. The utility function
$$ U(x) = \begin{cases}
x &\text{ if } x < 4 \\
x + 1 &\text{ if } x \geq 4
\end{cases}
$$
is discontinuous, but represents $\succeq$.

Any such function is necessarily have a continuous representation as well.

Comment: I would think that a proof would be showing that, in general, any continuous preference can be represented by a discontinuous utility function. I’ve now posted this as a [separate question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/52947/32979).