# Can every continuous preference relation be represented by a discontinuous utility function?

Tags: utility, preferences

In [this question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/24983/32979), it is shown that a continuous preference relation can have a discontinuous utility function.

Is it true in general that every continuous preference relation must have a discontinuous utility function?

I know that a continuous preference relation must have a continuous utility representation, and I am trying to compose such a continuous function with an increasing but discontinuous function (which will be a utility function for the preference relation), but since [the composition of a continuous and discontinuous function can be continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1655958/672549), it is not trivial to show this composition to be discontinuous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not true. Consider the continuous preference relation on $\mathbb{R}^n_+$ represented by utility function $u(x)= 0$. This does not have a discontinuous utility representation. In fact, this is the only continuous preference relation on $\mathbb{R}^n_+$ that does not have a discontinuous utility representation.

Comment: Would this mean that $\succsim=\mathbb R_+^n\times\mathbb R_+^n$ so that there is perfect indifference: $x\sim y$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb R_+^n?$

Comment: Yes that's right.